# .NET Uri class query missing the semicolon reserved character, simple workarounds?

Tags: c#, url, uri, standards-compliance

This https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx and this https://ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt suggest that the .Net Uri class does not recognize the semicolon as an acceptable character to represent a query in a URL.

This only requires one line or so to workaround, but I like my code clean. If there is a solution that allows me to not do string parsing myself outside the .Net set of Uri classes, I'd prefer that. Is there any existing .Net code that handles semicolons for recognizing them as part of a query in a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 3986 agrees with RFC 1738 (which it updates) in defining the query as a portion following a question mark (`?`), and in stating that a semicolon can be used to separate parameter-value pairs "applicable to that segment".

In a prospero URI (the only case given in RFC 1738 where a semicolon is shown used) semicolons indicate a parameter and parameter value in the path of the URI - not a query.

HTTP URIs do have semicolons used in their queries, but only after the `?`, e.g. `http://example.net/search?q=something;page=2`. Unfortunately actual usage has never quite replaced the `&` character for this function and it is poorly supported by server-side code (including ASP.NET) which limits the ability of client-side code to adopt it (pretty much no browser does).

Still, In such cases the .NET Uri object correctly identifies only that portion following the `?` as a query, including semicolons if present. Its behaviour is correct.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I misread the standard. I thought a semicolon could prefix any other special characters, not just replace the ampersand. Thanks.

Comment: With 1738 it wasn't terribly clear, though "query" is only used in the context of HTTP URIs, which at that point could only have & as the separator within the query while propsero URIs had something that was essentially doing the same job as a query and stuck at the end. So a that point whether you could consider that part of a propsero URI to be a query or not was unclear. RFC 1808 gave more detail in defining relative URIs, and ...

Comment: RFC 2396 continued this to full URIs (updating both 1738 and 1808). At this point, the meaning of "query" in URIs generally, rather than just in the case of HTTP, was made clearer, and it was stated as meaning the part after a question mark. These RFCs where in turn obsoleted by RFC 3986 / STD 66 which is the most current RFC on URIs.

Comment: Meanwhile, the idea of ; as a separator in URIs in HTTP URIs comes not from these RFCs (which says they can be used as parameter separators in any segment of a URI, but doesn't say other chars can't) but from HTML4.01 (a recommendation in one of the appendices). The HTTP URI standard is agnostic as to how content is encoded within the query as long as it produces a valid URI, and its the specification for application/x-www- form-urlencoded that gives us that (defined in HTML specs, and never registered with IANA). With all of that going on, it's not easy checking just what standard says what.